# Cannot install mongodb by npm on Win7

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

The node.js is v0.6.13.

> npm install mongodb 
>   it failed when it start GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.0.4

And I try to download mongo library from https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native
when I run 
var m=require('mongodb');
It said "Error: Cannot find module 'bson'"

Any Idea why this happend? Please give some advice
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try again, seems something changed in node 0.6.13 that broke it for everyone. I removed os checks completely so it should work fine now.

Comment: this problem looks to be back in node v0.6.17